# Handling multiple projects in TFS - some tools available?

Tags: tfs, multiple-projects

I am facing this ridiculous problem. I have more than 150 projects in tfs, and when i need to give admin rights to a particular person, or give portal rights, enable documents folder, change templates, get a combined report, etc, it gets tedious job to do it on all the projects...

Is anyone aware of such a tool that can work on multiple projects at a time ?

Comment: "when i need to ..." gives a great list of tasks you might be wanting to do, but we're never told of what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to ease the pain of managing permissions across TFS, SharePoint, and SQL Reporting Services, then this tool on codeplex can help:
http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've not come across anything that allows you to do this, the only thing you can do really is to make use of those AD groups.  If everything is organised into a decent structure (if not, move it :)) then the permissions should filter down, then it's just a matter of tweaking when needed.

Brian Harry's comments in response to Neil on Builds though:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/19/the-new-team-explorer-in-tfs-11.aspx imply that it's not going to be "fixed" (or significantly more awesome) next release though :(